# Add a dropdown to Highcharts to change chart type with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, highcharts

So I am trying to create a drop-down list that will turn my HighCharts from a bar chart to a pie graph whenever the user picks their selection I am positive I have the right code but I keep getting this error: **Cannot read property 'series' of undefined** I have gone though a dozen examples but none seem to apply that I have it inside an Angular Directive

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AngularJS + Highcarts </title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='css/highChartCss.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<select id="chartType">
    <option value="0">-select chart type-</option>
    <option value="line">line</option>
    <option value="column">column</option>
</select>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="graph">
    <section ng-app='charts'>
        <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
            <highchart chart='CDHLeads'></highchart>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/webSocket.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/highChartAngular.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**highChartAngular.js**

```
function log() {
    var formattedDate = new Date();
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = formattedDate;
}
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#0266C8', '#0EE', '#F93', '#DDDF00', '#F90101']
});

function buildChart(title, yAxisLabel, xAxisLabels, series) {
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'CDHLeads',
                type: 'column',
                backgroundColor: '#000000'
            },
            legend: {
                itemStyle: {
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    font: '12pt Inconsolata, sans-serif',
                    color: '#FFF'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: title,
                style: {
                    font: '12pt Inconsolata, sans-serif',
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: xAxisLabels,
                style: {
                    font: '12pt Inconsolata, sans-serif',
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {

                series: {
                    colorByPoint: false
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: yAxisLabel
                },
                tyle: {
                    font: '12pt Inconsolata, sans-serif',
                    color: 'white'
                }
            },
            series: series
        });
    });
    $("#chartType").change(function() {
        var type = this.value;
        if(type !== '0') {
            var cdh = $('#CDHLeads').highcharts();
            $(cdh.series).each(function(){
                this.update({
                    type: type
                }, false);
            });
            cdh.redraw();
        }
    });
}

var app = angular.module('charts', []);

app.directive('highchart', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div id="container">',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(attrs.chart, function () {

                if (!attrs.chart) return;

                var chart = scope.$eval(attrs.chart);

                angular.element(element).highcharts(chart);
            });

        }
    }
}]);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.example_chart = buildChart();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead

```
var cdh = $('#CDHLeads').highcharts();
```

use

```
var cdh = $('#container').highcharts();
```

because in your template , container is the chart id.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's the following two lines that are the problem:

```
var cdh = $('#CDHLeads').highcharts();
$(cdh.series).each(function(){
```

What the error message is telling you is that `cdh` is undefined.  I think it's because `$('#CDHLeads')` isn't actually finding the chart element you're after at you've not set the ID field.  I'd try changing:

```
<highchart chart='CDHLeads'></highchart>
```

to

```
<highchart id="CDHLeads" chart='CDHLeads'></highchart>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the response but  now nothing is appearing and there are no new errors to explain why